# ReportManager Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Can anyone help me setup this software with a Firebird Database?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/reportman/

Or do you know another software that reads .rep files ?

Everytime I try to setup, i get fbclient.dll or gds32.dll error 126

And when somehow i get the connection "working" the software gives me a "Subreport alias not found."

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to install Firebird SQL Server from this site: http://firebirdsql.org/

Comment: I have firebird already installed, the problem is that report manager doesnt want to connect to the database or I just dont know how to, i tried many things and couldnt do it